# A graph of 6 vertices with 6 edges of length 2 and 9 edges of length 1.

Tags: graph-theory

Find a graph with 6 vertices and unit edge lengths with 9 pairs of vertices $x, y$ such that $d(x, y) = 1$, and 6 pairs of vertices $x,y$ satisfying $d(x, y) = 2$.

I was not successful to create such a graph. Is there any systematic method to go about it? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

With $6$ vertices there are $15=\binom 62$ pairs of vertices.

You are told to have $9$ pairs at distance $1$. The pairs at distance $1$ are those connected by an edge, so you need exactly $9$ edges.

Then you need $6$ pairs, that is, all the rest, at distance $2$. That means you must choose your $9$ edges in such a way that for every pair $x,y$ that doesn't have an edge between, there is another vertex $z$ with edges to both $x$ and $y$.

It might be simpler to choose the six pairs without edges instead (i.e. think about the complement). There are not that many things to try - you should be able to find one that works.

Answer (score 2):

Draw the vertices $v_i$ $(i\in{\mathbb Z}_6)$ of a regular hexagon, and join these vertices with the $9$ inner diagonals. You then have $9$ pairs of adjacent vertices and $6$ pairs of nonadjacent vertices, namely the successive pairs $\{v_i, v_{i+1}\}$.

Answer (score 1):

A star with $4$ extra edges works. There are $9$ edges and every two vertices are at distance maximum $2$.